# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Note that I have read answers to questions of the same issue but no one is like mine.

I loaded a picture in OpenCV and displayed it. Everything is fine.

Now I want to set black pixels to blue, so I run this:

```
for i in range(image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(image.shape[1]):
       if image[i,j,0]==0 and image[i,j,1]==0 and image[i,j,2]==0:
          image[i,j,0]=255
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

**Nota Bene:**

- The notations `image[i,j,0]`, `image[i,j,1]` and  `image[i,j,2]` underline the value of the channel of a pixel (BGR= Blue Green Red) so it is not an array as this error message says. So strange if Python does not understand itself.
- When I run `print image[i,j,x]`, with `x` =0,1,2 I get normal behavior for random values of `i` and `j`. That is, I get the values of those 3 channels correctly.

Comment: Try replacing your condition check with this: `if (image[i,j,0]==0) & (image[i,j,0]==0) & (image[i,j,0]==0):` I think the problem here is that when comparing arrays you have to use the bitwise operators, additonally you have to use brackets because of operator precedecnce

Comment: To give some context around EdChum's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous

Comment: @EdChum I did what you said, but trust me it tells me exactly the same error message

Comment: @YannickMeeus Thanks. I did but same error. Also, note that image[i,j,0] for example is not an array but just the first color channel of a pixel i, j (blue)

Comment: EdChum is definitely right about this, so there may be something up with your array. Have you tried `print image[3,3,0], image[3,3,1], image[3,3,2]` for example. (Note the different indexes on the last axis: in your question they're all 0.

Comment: @xnx it is just a typo, thank you, in my original program it is as i edited it now, and the printing works fine for random values of i and j

Comment: @KillianDS Thank you. But I had this issue since yesterday morning and tried all what I could read similar to my issue here, so I asked a moment ago

Comment: What line does the traceback point to?

Comment: @RobertKern thank you. The trackedback point is the line where there is `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

image[np.all(image == 0, axis=-1)] = [255, 0, 0]
```

Here you check only the Z axis using numpy operations, and replace it with blue for which the pixel channels are all 0.
It is an infinity quicker (at least for large images) and is also less devious.